# Make SQLAlchemy Errors more user friendly and detailed

Tags: python, flask, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

I've got a model like this:

```
class Company(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = "my_table"
    id = db.Column(db.Integer(), primary_key=True)
    name = db.Column(db.String(128), unique=True, nullable=False)
    slug = db.Column(db.String(128), unique=True, nullable=False)
```

As you can see I'm using `Flask-SQLAlchemy`'s classes and methods, but that's not the point,
Let's say I have a view which executes this lines:

```
c = Company("Test", "test")
try:
    db.session.add(c)
    db.session.commit()
    return "Added!"
except Exception as e:
    db.session.rollback()
    return f"{e}"
```

The code above, creates an object of `Company`, tries to add it to database, rollbacks the transaction on exception,

The problem is here, since the data is hardcoded, it should always return the exception, SQLAlchemy raises an [`IntegrityError`](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/errors.html?highlight=error#integrityerror).

The `IntegrityError` is so freaking ugly and useless for user, example:

```
(sqlite3.IntegrityError) UNIQUE constraint failed: my_table.name [SQL: 'INSERT INTO my_table (name, slug) VALUES (?, ?)'] [parameters: ('Test', 'tests')] (Background on this error at: http://sqlalche.me/e/gkpj)
```

**I'm looking for a way to make it prettified and user friendly**, before this I was using `db.validates` decorator and check for duplicated data on validation, but that feels wrong to me

The least thing I need is finding out what field is causing the problem without hardcoding

Answer (score 7, accepted):

SQLAlchemy includes a mechanism to allow customization of DBAPI errors  using the [handle_error](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/core/events.html?highlight=handle_error#sqlalchemy.events.ConnectionEvents.handle_error) event hook.   I made use of this API in Openstack [oslo.db](https://github.com/openstack/oslo.db) which can be seen in this file: https://github.com/openstack/oslo.db/blob/master/oslo_db/sqlalchemy/exc_filters.py.

Since stackoverflow hates links to code, here's a POC based on the above linked approach:

```
import collections
from sqlalchemy import event
from sqlalchemy import exc as sqla_exc
import re


class DuplicateKeyError(Exception):
    """Duplicate entry at unique column error."""

    def __init__(self, columns=None, inner_exception=None, value=None):
        self.columns = columns or []
        self.value = value
        self.inner_exception = inner_exception

    def __str__(self):
        return "Duplicate key for columns %s" % (
            self.columns,
        )


_registry = collections.defaultdict(lambda: collections.defaultdict(list))


def filters(ame, exception_type, regex):
    """Mark a function as receiving a filtered exception."""

    def _receive(fn):
        _registry[ame][exception_type].extend(
            (fn, re.compile(reg))
            for reg in ((regex,) if not isinstance(regex, tuple) else regex)
        )
        return fn

    return _receive


# each @filters() lists a database name, a SQLAlchemy exception to catch,
# and a list of regular expressions that will be matched.  If all the
# conditions match, the handler is called which then raises a nicer
# error message.

@filters(
    "sqlite",
    sqla_exc.IntegrityError,
    (
        r"^.*columns?(?P<columns>[^)]+)(is|are)\s+not\s+unique$",
        r"^.*UNIQUE\s+constraint\s+failed:\s+(?P<columns>.+)$",
        r"^.*PRIMARY\s+KEY\s+must\s+be\s+unique.*$",
    ),
)
def _sqlite_dupe_key_error(integrity_error, match, engine_name, is_disconnect):
    columns = []
    try:
        columns = match.group("columns")
        columns = [c.split(".")[-1] for c in columns.strip().split(", ")]
    except IndexError:
        pass

    raise DuplicateKeyError(columns, integrity_error)


@filters(
    "mysql",
    sqla_exc.IntegrityError,
    r"^.*\b1062\b.*Duplicate entry '(?P<value>.*)'"
    r" for key '(?P<columns>[^']+)'.*$",
)
@filters(
    "postgresql",
    sqla_exc.IntegrityError,
    (
        r'^.*duplicate\s+key.*"(?P<columns>[^"]+)"\s*\n.*'
        r"Key\s+\((?P<key>.*)\)=\((?P<value>.*)\)\s+already\s+exists.*$",
        r"^.*duplicate\s+key.*\"(?P<columns>[^\"]+)\"\s*\n.*$",
    ),
)
def _default_dupe_key_error(
    integrity_error, match, engine_name, is_disconnect
):
    columns = match.group("columns")
    uniqbase = "uniq_"
    if not columns.startswith(uniqbase):
        if engine_name == "postgresql":
            columns = [columns[columns.index("_") + 1 : columns.rindex("_")]]
        else:
            columns = [columns]
    else:
        columns = columns[len(uniqbase) :].split("0")[1:]

    value = match.groupdict().get("value")

    raise DuplicateKeyError(columns, integrity_error, value)


def handler(context):
    """Iterate through available filters and invoke those which match.
    The first one which raises wins.
    """

    def _dialect_registries(engine):
        if engine.dialect.name in _registry:
            yield _registry[engine.dialect.name]
        if "*" in _registry:
            yield _registry["*"]

    for per_dialect in _dialect_registries(context.engine):
        for exc in (context.sqlalchemy_exception, context.original_exception):
            for super_ in exc.__class__.__mro__:
                if super_ in per_dialect:
                    regexp_reg = per_dialect[super_]
                    for fn, regexp in regexp_reg:
                        match = regexp.match(exc.args[0])
                        if match:
                            fn(
                                exc,
                                match,
                                context.engine.dialect.name,
                                context.is_disconnect,
                            )


if __name__ == '__main__':
    from sqlalchemy import Column, Integer, String, create_engine
    from sqlalchemy.orm import Session
    from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base

    Base = declarative_base()


    class Company(Base):
        __tablename__ = "my_table"
        id = Column(Integer(), primary_key=True)
        name = Column(String(128), unique=True, nullable=False)
        slug = Column(String(128), unique=True, nullable=False)

        def __init__(self, name, slug):
            self.name = name
            self.slug = slug

    e = create_engine("sqlite://", echo=True)
    Base.metadata.create_all(e)
    event.listen(e, "handle_error", handler)

    s = Session(e)
    s.add(Company("Test", "test"))
    s.commit()


    s.add(Company("Test", "test"))
    s.commit()
```

Running it, we see:

```
2019-03-13 09:44:51,701 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.base.Engine INSERT INTO my_table (name, slug) VALUES (?, ?)
2019-03-13 09:44:51,701 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.base.Engine ('Test', 'test')

2019-03-13 09:44:53,387 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.base.Engine ROLLBACK
Traceback (most recent call last):
# ...
sqlite3.IntegrityError: UNIQUE constraint failed: my_table.slug

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
 # ...
__main__.DuplicateKeyError: Duplicate key for columns ['slug']
```

Comment: It seems to be the answer that I needed, I'll give it a try as soon as I can

Answer (score 1):

Generally speaking you could `try/except` the error to "catch" it, log the error and then return a custom error to the user. Like this:

```py
c = Company("Test", "test")
try:
    db.session.add(c)
    db.session.commit()
    return "Added!"
except Exception as e:
    db.session.rollback()
    return f"failed to insert company: {e.__class__.__name__}"
```

That seems like a fast answer not the right one. Instead I would add some validation before attempting the insert:

```py
c = Company("Test", "test")
# note this is pseudo code
if Company.find.get("Test"):
    try:
        db.session.add(c)
        db.session.commit()
        return "Added!"
    except Exception as e:
        db.session.rollback()
        return f"failed to insert company: {e.__class__.__name__}"
else:
return f"company {c.id} already exists"
```

That way you aren't raising an error, instead your application is handling its' data vs. failing to insert.

Comment: Thanks for the fast answer, the second way is kinda the same with my checking at validation method

Comment: Your second way may still raise the error, since another request may commit between the check and trying to insert, so it is better to just handle the constraint violation.

Comment: @IljaEverilä currently I'm using `db.validates` decorator, if another row with the same data found, I raise a `ValueError` and handle it in the view by putting object initialization in the `try/except` block, But I'm looking for a better way

Answer (score 1):

You can import the `exception` and then, handle it yourself:

```
from sqlite3.__init__ import IntegrityError
```

this will give you the exception name, then you can do something like:

```
except IntegrityError :
    db.session.rollback()
    return f"duplicate data has been used!"
```

or however else you would need to handle this exception.

remember though, this will only catch the error if you are using the `sqlite` package, and not the `sqlalchemy` so if you changed the `db engine`  somewhere along the way, you may not be able to handle this `exception`.

```
from sqlalchemy.exc import IntegrityError
```

is the exception `class` you would need to raise for the `sqlalchemy` raised exceptions.